# vertically center header text

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am looking to increase the size of the header of a jquery mobile app.  When I do that I need the title to be centred.  I found that I can add a line like:

```
        line-height: 30px;
```

to the css, but that is just far to much of a hack.  I assume there must be a better way to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css"><!--
            .ui-header {
                height: 50px;                
            }
            -->
        </style>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>This Needs To Be Centred Vertically</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Page content goes here.</p>   
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to vertically center text of a block element is by making the line-height the same as the height of said element. Note that this will only work if you have a single line of text.

```
line-height: 30px;
height: 30px;
```

On an inline or table-cell element, you could use `vertical-align: middle` to achieve the same effect.

Also note that forcing `display: table-cell` on an element will not work in IE6-7.

In your case, I would suggest going with the line-height/height technique.

Comment: Thanks.  Your line/line-height solution is the simplest I've found yet.  It works well in jQuery Mobile to center stuff in the header.

Comment: do have also an solutuion for a content with 2 lines ?

Comment: It depends if you know you'll exactly have 2 lines of text or if the text length is variable. I highly recommend this blog post by Chris Coyier about vertically centering multi-lines text : http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 0):

You may try with

```
display: table-cell; 
vertical-align: middle;
```

in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<div data-role="header">
   <div class="ui-bar">
      <h1>This Needs To Be Centred Vertically</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Doc: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html