# jquery mobile vertical align back button

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have been using back button in jquery mobile page what i need is to vertically align the back button. in the header

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some HTML/CSS code, as our crystal balls are currently out of order :/.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this web site for the answer (as well as detailed explanation of the problem with vertical alignment): http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: That's a great article.  Vertical alignment definitely needs fixing in HTML (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `top` value using the following css rule.

```
.ui-header .ui-btn-left {
    top: 0.6em;/*Adjust this value*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another stackoverflow post that seems related to your question.  It includes a workable solution (elegant and not too hackish).  Nevertheless, I hope the jQuery Mobile folks (bless their hearts) make a standard way to specify vertical alignment in any table or grid.

[Stackoverflow Post 8280637](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280637/vertically-center-header-text)

Answer (score 0):

I know, its old task but... I have to classes to make this.
One for just vertically center something, one for vertically and horizontally:

```
.h-centered-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%)
}

.vh-centered-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Just apply it to the element you want to center vertically or both